# Download Random File From Directory

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a directory named /kv/ and I want it so when you go to blah.com/getkv.php it will download a random file from the directory. If possible, I want it to delete the file after it's been downloaded as well. All help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You could store files in numerical order than then select one at random by generating a random number.

```
$random = mt_rand(1,100); //The amount of files you have
```

Next once you have a file selected you would set the download headers

```
$file="/path/to/file/".$random.".png"; //file location
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Finally deleting the file with

```
delete($file);
```

---

Another way of selecting a random file would be indexing a folder, and then chosing one of those files at random.

It would also be wise to have checks in place to make sure that the file exists.

Comment: `range (1,100)` will give you an array of 1-100, not a random number. did you mean `mt_rand(1,100)`?

Comment: @chiliNUT sorry about that, i'm very tired haha

Answer (score 1):

Here's some PHP to get a random file from a directory:

```
$files = glob('*.{php,html}', GLOB_BRACE);
$file = $files[rand(0,count($files) - 1)];
```

Then add part of the answer provided by viralpickaxe:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

...and delete the file from the directory:

```
unlink($file);
```